# jquery tooltipster plugin, hide all tips?

Tags: jquery, tooltipster

if I have bound tooltipster to input elements and to a diferent elements like a div, is there a way I can hide all in a single call?

So far I know I can to this by hand with:

$('form input').tooltipster('hide');
$('#mydiv').tooltipster('hide');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple, you just need to separate your selectors [by comma](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
$('form input, #mydiv').tooltipster('hide');
```

If you don't know exact elements that contain tooltipster you can use `filter` method:

```
$('*').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('tooltipsterNs');
}).tooltipster('hide');
```

Comment: Yes I know I can do it that way also, but some of the divs are created dynamically and I cannot pass the names into the tooltipster, that is why I want to close them all in a single call dynamically. In fact is a close all function.

Comment: Have you tried to use asterisk as your selector? `$('*').tooltipster('hide');`

Comment: do you know a way to close them all in a single call I do not know like with qtip2: $('.qtip.ui-tooltip').qtip('hide');

Comment: Yes and it says that I called "Tooltipster's "hide" method on an uninitialized element". because it will call all elements including those that are not initialized, also using "*" will have some performance issues.

Comment: it will be great to find out which elements are bound witouth knowing their name and at the same time destroy or hide them.

Comment: @IvanJuarez See my updated answer. Unfortunately tooltipster doesn't attach classes or other DOM indicators that can be selected using regular jQuery selectors so only filtering elements by `tooltipsterNs` data property will help there. And yes, it's bad from performance perspective but I don't see any good solution for this that can be achieved in one line

Comment: Man you know how to use jQuery correctly, blessings.

Comment: in a further time we will be switching from tooltipster to any other, or simply use bootstrap tooltips.

Answer (score 16):

Tooltipster does add a CSS class to elements that have a tooltip attached : "tooltipstered".

So one technique among others is to call

`$('.tooltipstered').tooltipster('close');`

**Edit**: with Tooltipster v4, you can actually do this with the public methods, which is always better. Besides, it also works when you use tooltips with the `multiple` option, while my previous answer does not:

```
var instances = $.tooltipster.instances();
$.each(instances, function(i, instance){
    instance.close();
});
```

Comment: `.tooltipster('close')` didn't work for me on 3.0.6. But `.tooltipster('hide')` worked fine.